# React App makes Window File Explorer frozen

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, npm, npm-install

I used the npm command to create react app, after that my laptop fan started to get louder and when I tried to open any folder it's just not responding. File Explorer is frozen, it said loading the files but it will take forever. I just can't do my work.

- I tried to restart File Explorer from task manager and it won't work.
- The only way to fix it is to restart my laptop, but it will happen again sometimes even if I don't do anything with the react project. I just need to restart it a couple of times until it back to normal
- The first time it happens I wasn't sure because it was the first time I tried to create react and my laptop also had some problems at the time, so I leave the react project for a month.
- The second time is yesterday. When I tried to create react app again, File Explorer got freezing.
- All this happen after I used the npm command.

Does someone know the answer? I've been trying to learn react and this makes me discouraged. Please help. (Sorry for my poor English)

Answer (score 0):

I think your pc can't handle create react app. It's very heavy and consumes everything in your pc. Probably if you just let it install without using anything it will be ok.